# Understanding terminology: analyticity, smoothness, continuity, holomophism

Tags: complex-analysis, terminology

**Question:** This question is asking whether my understanding of the terminology and concepts of complex analysis is correct.

Please do comment/answer if the following are correct or false:

1. An **analytic** function is one that can be represented by a **convergent Taylor series** at every point in its domain.
2. Because Taylor series can be differentiated infinitely, analytic functions are not just **continuous**, they are **smooth**. Smoothness is a stronger property because continuous just means no gaps.
3. If a complex function is analytic, then it is also infinitely differentiable. The reverse is also true, if a complex function is infinitely differentiable, then it is analytic.
4. A complex differentiable (Cauchy-Riemann conditions) function is called **holomorphic**.
5. The terms analytic and holomorphic are used interchangeably for complex functions because of this equivalence, but they have distinct historical origins.
6. The equivalence of smoothness (infinitely differentiable) and analyticity (Taylor series) is a special property of complex functions. It is not always true for real functions(*).

(*) Regarding the last point, a common example of a smooth real function that is not analytic is $f(x)=0$ for $x<0$ and $f(x)=e^{-1/x^2}$ for $x\geq0$. This is clearly infinitely differentiable. Why is it not analytic?

Comment: Regarding your last question, what would be the Taylor series of that function at $x=0$?

Comment: I would add that in the complex case, (one time) complex differentiability on an open set without any other conditions is enough to imply analyticity (there are even weaker conditions like the existence of partial derivatives that are locally integrable and satisfy C-R on an open set) and hence infinite differentiability, so there are no gradations of differentiability as opposed to the real case where we have various gradations like $C^k$ ($k$ times differentiable with the $k$th derivative continuous) or similar ($k$ times differentiable but with weaker conditions on the $k$th derivative)

Comment: @Joe - the Taylor series would be "0" when developed about $x=0$. This gives the correct value at $x=0$. I can't see the problem. Is the requirement for the radius of convergence to be non-zero?

Comment: Yes, the radius is required to be positive. A function is analytic at a point $x$ if the function is equal to its Taylor series on some open set containing $x$.

Comment: If a function is equal to a convergent power series, $f(x) = \sum a_n (x-b)^n$ on some open set containing $b$, then that power series is the Taylor series, which can be shown by differentiating the power series. But every function (analytic or not) is equal to a convergent power series at just one point, by letting $a_0 = f(b)$ and $a_n = 0$ for $n>0$.

Comment: thanks @Joe that last comment was very enlightening

Comment: You're welcome. I'm happy I could help.